# How to measure distance of value in Hypothesis test?

Tags: calculus, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

If Null hypothesis is $p_1 =p_2$ and Alternative hypothesis is $p_1 <p_2$ then the p value can only show us the how strong the evidence is to support or against the null hypothesis. But what test we can use to test the difference of two values?
For example p1 is 3 and p2 is 3.5 vs p1 is 3 and p2 is 80 we may get same $p$ value = 95%

Answer (score 0):

**An approximate normal test of the difference between two binomial proportions.**

It is not clear to me what sample sizes and numbers of successes you have. Perhaps it is easiest to explain this in terms of a specific numerical
example, in which this information is available:

Suppose you have two political parties and you want to know
whether the proportion of women is the same in each.
You sample 160 people from Party 1 and get 81 women, and you
sample 180 from Party 2 and get 99 women. Then estimated
proportions $\hat p_1 = 81/160 = 0.506$ and $\hat p_2 = 99/180 =0.55.$
You want to test $H_0: p_1 = p_2$ against $H_a: p_1 \ne p_2.$

We have
$E(\hat p_1) = p_1$ and $Var(\hat p_1) = \frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n_1}$
and similarly for $\hat p_2.$ Using the normal approximation
to each binomial proportion, approximating $p_i$ by $\hat p_i$ and
standardizing the difference $\hat p_1 - \hat p_2,$ we have the (approximate) test statistic
$$Z = \frac{\hat p_1 - \hat p_2}{SE(\hat p_1 - \hat p_2)},$$
where $SE(\hat p_1 - \hat p_2) = 
\sqrt{\frac{\hat p_1(1-\hat p_1)}{n_1}+\frac{\hat p_2(1-\hat p_2)}{n_2}}$
and $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ under $H_0.$ [The sample sizes $n_1 - 160$ and $n_2 = 180$ are sufficiently large that the normal approximation is
reliable, especially since $\hat p_1$ and $\hat p_2$ are near 1/2.]

In Minitab statistical software the test looks like this:

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample   X    N  Sample p
1       81  160  0.506250
2       99  180  0.550000

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.04375
95% CI for difference:  (-0.149973, 0.0624731)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = -0.81  P-Value = 0.420
```

Because the test statistic has $|Z| = 0.81 < 1.96$ we cannot reject the null
hypothesis that parties have the same proportions of women--at the 5% level
of significance. The sample proportions do differ, but not by a statistically significant amount.

An alternative way to reach the same conclusion is to note
that the P-value $0.42 > .05.$ The P-value is the total $P(Z \le -0.81) + P(Z \ge 0.81),$ where $Z \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1);$ that is, the probability
assuming $H_0$ to be true, of observing a discrepancy in
sample proportions as large as what we had in our samples or larger.

Finally, in terms of confidence intervals,
we note that the 95% confidence interval includes $0,$ so that it
is reasonable to say that data are consistent with no difference in
proportions. The confidence interval is computed as $\hat p_1 -\hat p_2 \pm
1.96SE(\hat p_1 - \hat p_2).$

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to find the other group of population says: group 3, but with different sample size and come out with different sample proportion. But by measuring between group 2 and group 3, the Z value (or P value) is the same? If this is the case, how can we differentiate group 1 and group 3?

Comment: Consider a $3 \times 2$ table with counts from Groups 1, 2, 3 in the rows and counts of Women and Men in the columns. You want to know if row distributions of W vs. M are homogeneous across Groups. Chi-Squared statistic has 2 degrees of freedom. Search for 'test of homogeneity' or 'contingency table' in stat text or online. If signif differences found, look at 'Pearson residuals' for clues where homogeneity fails.